# setting z order of View with bringChildToFront()

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the z order of a UI element (i.e. a View) so that it will overlap another element, but calling ViewGroup.bringChildToFront() has a weird side effect....it moves the element to be the last item in the parent (the ViewGroup).  Is this a bug, expected behavior, or what?  More importantly, how can I set the z order or a View without this unfortunate side effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. bringChildToFront() just changes the index of the View inside its parent.

Answer (score 15):

To send a view all the way back, do this:

```
private void moveToBack(View currentView) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup) currentView.getParent());
    int index = viewGroup.indexOfChild(currentView);
    for(int i = 0; i<index; i++) {
        viewGroup.bringChildToFront(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: "i" instead of "0" at `vg.bringChildToFront(vg.getChildAt(0));`

Comment: This answer is actually not correct, although it's close. Because `bringChildToFront()` reorders the list each time it's called, calling it like this does not work as you expect. Instead you would have to for example first store all the children you want to bring to front in a temporary array, and then in a second loop through that array call `bringChildToFront()` using the entries from the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

`bringChildToFront(child)` does nothing but changes the index value of the child.

In order to bring a child to the front without using `showNext()` or `showprevious()`,

use

`setDisplayedChild()` and `indexOfChild()` together.

example

`vf.setDisplayedChild(vf.indexOfChild(child));`

where **child** is the **view** that needs to be brought front.

Thanks

Comment: Only when your parent view is a `ViewFlipper`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that was a headache. For my requirements of getting correct animation without chaotic overlapping in `GridView` I made the next utility method:

```
    /**
    * Rearrange Z value of the
    * @param view chosen element in the viewGroup
    * @param onTop if true (or sent back if false)
    */
public static void setViewZOrder(ViewGroup viewGroup, View view, boolean onTop) {
    int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    TextView child;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        child = (TextView) viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        child.setZ(0.5F);
    }
    view.setZ(onTop ? 1.0F : 0.0F);
    viewGroup.invalidate();
    // TODO: 06.03.2024 the first element still uncontrollable
}
```

Still don't know how to solve last comment, it seems `viewGroup.getChildAt(0)` is aways "below" the others, even if it returns `getZ()` properly set to 0.0F or 1.0F or 100.0F.