# Z order in xml android

Tags: android, layout

can someone give me a good explanation regarding Z order. Firstly, I don't understand what it is and(something like the definition)and secondly how an element of a Z order looks like. I hope I am explicit enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Z order determines how objects lay on each other - that is which one is on top. [This is good example for HTML](http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php) (with example pictures). In android is simpler (that is in my opinion conception is simpler, but usage could be less easy) since there is no explicit z index. If you use xml layout z order is determined by [order of declaration views declaration in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android) but if you prefer [you can also change order from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740100/setting-z-order-of-view-with-bringchildtofront).

Comment: thanks mate for clearing this up for me. I was having some doubts regardin this. I was thinking that either it's something like i have a linear layout a text view(Z index 0 for example) and then if i have another linear layout inside if this next linear layout has other text view the Z index will be 1 or like you just said. So thanks again

Comment: Any way of doing this without changing the order?

Answer (score 1):

Starting on Android API level 21 the Z order is also affected by the `android:elevation` for a more detailed explanation see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38536318/2168700