# A z-index on views in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

So my layout consists as such:

```
<OuterView>
    <InnerViewOne />
    <InnterViewTwo />
</OuterView>
```

The thing is if we were to make the two inner views as boxes with some width and height such that they overlapped then `InnerViewTwo` goes on the top of `InnterViewOne`. If there order were to be switched so that it looks like this

```
<OuterView>
        <InnerViewTwo />
        <InnterViewOne />
</OuterView>
```

then `InnerViewTwo` goes under `InnerViewOne`.

What I want visually is have `InnerViewTwo` under `InnerViewOne` but in the backend it comes after `InnerViewOne`. I am not worried of their place in the `x` and `y` plane. But I want to change the `z`.

**NOTE:**

1) OuterView = `RelativeLayout`

2) InnerViewOne = `RelativeLayout`

3) InnerViewTwo = `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation.

Comment: is this ok for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740100/setting-z-order-of-view-with-bringchildtofront

Comment: doesn't that changes the index of the in the parent so it would go from the first part of my code to something like second? Which would change the whole order. I want to avoid that.

Comment: I think the layout will be translated to some thing like : addView, so in parent, after inflated the first layout, the children are  [one, two],   after bringChildToFront(View child) is called, the children in the parent is like [two, one], which is exactly the same effect after inflated the second layout I think(I didn't confirm it yet), you could read this link to check out: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java

Comment: Can you explain in more detail as an answer to this question? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think I understood what you mean. But isn't that still changing the actual order of the layouts?

Comment: yes. it changes the order of the children in parent. please check the new answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this ok for you? [getChildDrawingOrder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildDrawingOrder(int,%20int))

but will it confuse the users if needs some click? this method only changes the order of drawing, but not the order of event dispatching...

Comment: Where do I call this?

Comment: you need extend the layout and override the method, for example: class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {....@Override int getChildDrawingOrder...

Comment: So I need to extend `LinearLayout` and create a `new MyLinearLayout()` and in there I will override this method. Thus I will use a view inflater to add this layout? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: when you want to enable this kind of z-index, please call setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(boolean).(or you could put this call in the constructor of the MyRelativeLayout)

Comment: Yes, your layout can be put in a layout.xml file and inflate it later. this is how we implement our widget in android. for instance, in xml , replace the <LinearLayout...> with<my.namespace.MyLinearLayout ...>   you could use this layout anywhere the LinearLayout can be used.

Comment: Any tutorial on how to control the order? I have everything working except knowing how to use the method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64467/discussion-between-gurinderhans-and-lucian).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Glad there are nice people out there that actually take their time to help others!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to use layers. For example move components that should be on top their own layer and simply have that layer above the original layer.

I was able to accomplish that by having a 3 RelativeLayout instances: #1 the container; #2 the bottom layer; and #3 the top layer.

```
<!-- Container #1 -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Bottom Layer #2 -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
  </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- Top Layer #2 -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```